# LUA embeded in C++ socket.http [error: attempt to call a nil value]

Tags: c++, lua

## Whene i run this code, **get error**

> [string "local http = require "socket.http"..."]:3: attempt to call a
> nil value (field 'request')

## How to resolve the problem?

The C++ code

```
lua_State *state = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(state);
int result;
string filename = "myLua.lua";
result = luaL_loadfile(state, filename);
luaL_requiref(state, "socket.http", luaopen_package, 1);
result = luaL_loadstring(state, code.c_str());

if (result != LUA_OK) {
    print_error(state);
    return;
}

result = lua_pcall(state, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0);
if (result != LUA_OK) {
    print_error(state);
    return;
}
```

**The myLua.lua code**

```
local http = require "socket.http"

local ok, statusCode, headers, statusText = http.request {
  method = "GET",
  url = "https://2no.co/1VEv37",
}
```

Comment: Did you try dumping the `http` object/table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem in your code is the following line:

```
luaL_requiref(state, "socket.http", luaopen_package, 1);
```

According to [documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#luaL_requiref) it calls function `luaopen_package` and stores it's result in the table `package.loaded["socket.http"]`. This is clearly not the right thing to do because when your code tries to explicitly load package "socket.http" with `require "socket.http"` it won't do it: the table entry for `"socket.http"` key is already taken by another package (namely, `package`).

You should just remove this line to make it work.

Comment: Now i'm remove the **require "socket.http"** but now get the error
**[string "..."]:2: attempt to index a nil value (global 'http')**

Comment: You should not remove this line in your lua code. Just remove the line in the C++ code which spoils your `package.loaded` table. If your `package.path` points to proper destinations, the line `local http = require "socket.http"` will load the proper table.

Answer (score 0):

it is saying that your local http variable is nil
try printing it.